# WHERE CASE WHEN SQL for time interval

Tags: sql

SQL to filter the BrandCode when customer visit time not between (during KFC hour is closed.)

```
SELECT * 
FROM EatTime e 
LEFT JOIN CloseHour c 
    ON DATEPART(weekday, e.VisitDate) = DATEPART(weekday, c.MonthDate) 
WHERE (
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEPART(weekday,e.VisitDate) = 1 
            THEN (e.VisitTime NOT BETWEEN '10:00:00' AND '13:00:00')
        WHEN DATEPART(weekday,e.VisitDate) = 3 
            THEN (e.VisitTime NOT BETWEEN '21:00:00' AND '22:00:00')
    END
)
```

Here is some sample data:

```
CustomerId BrandCode  Visit  VisitTime  VisitDate  Brand  CloseHR  MonthDate
         1 Skake          1  10:05:22   2018/2/4   KFC    10:00:00 2018/2/4
         1 Skake          1  10:05:22   2018/2/4   KFC    11:00:00 2018/2/4
         1 Skake          1  10:05:22   2018/2/4   KFC    12:00:00 2018/2/4
         1 Skake          1  10:05:22   2018/2/4   KFC    13:00:00 2018/2/4
         2 KFC            1  11:05:22   2018/2/6   KFC    21:00:00 2018/2/6
         2 KFC            1  11:05:22   2018/2/6   KFC    22:00:00 2018/2/6
         3 BurgerKing     1  12:05:22   2018/2/4   KFC    10:00:00 2018/2/4
         4 Denny          1  13:05:22   2018/2/4   KFC    10:00:00 2018/2/4
```

Comment: Do you have open and close times in the CloseHour table. Is it different for different brands and for different days of the week?

Comment: I removed the mysql tag.  This code is not MySQL.  Sample data and desired results -- in a text, tabular format -- would really help.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry - well done for tidying up that horrible HTML table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you searching for something like this:

```
SELECT* 
FROM EatTime e 
LEFT JOIN CloseHour c
    ON DATEPART(weekday, e.VisitDate) = DATEPART(weekday, c.MonthDate) 
WHERE 
( 
    (
        DATEPART(weekday, e.VisitDate) = 1 
        AND e.VisitTime NOT BETWEEN '10:00:00' AND '13:00:00'
    )
    OR 
    ( 
        DATEPART(weekday, e.VisitDate) = 3
        AND e.VisitTime NOT BETWEEN '21:00:00' AND '22:00:00'
    )
)
```